# Trouble Mounting NTFS drive on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount, ntfs

Mounting NTFS drives works [in OS X natively](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/). [Mounting drives with fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) is common and can be seen [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/13/mount-unmount-drives-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/) and [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-write-to-a-ntfs-drive-from-os-x-mavericks/) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/lq-zfq).

I was able to successfully do it with the following addition to my fstab.

```
UUID=30ADE88E-0889-42FF-AEC3-3AE0D11C7FE4 none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

However, on reboot the next time I plugged in my drive it no longer worked.

I tried `sudo mount -a` but that failed with the following error:

```
mount: realpath /none: No such file or directory
```

The `diskutil` command is my go-to for finding drive information.

```
➜  /  diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 512ssd                  499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS 900GBWD                 900.2 GB   disk1s1 <--- SEE
   2:             Windows_FAT_32 100GBWDFAT              100.0 GB   disk1s2
```

Once you know your drive location in `/dev` then you can find the UUID with `diskutil info disk1s1`:

```
➜  /  diskutil info disk1s1
   Device Identifier:        disk1s1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      Untitled 1

   Volume Name:              900GBWD
   Escaped with Unicode:     900GBWD

   Mounted:                  No

   File System Personality:  NTFS
   Type (Bundle):            ntfs
   Name (User Visible):      Windows NT File System (NTFS)

   Partition Type:           Windows_NTFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              30ADE88E-0889-42FF-AEC3-3AE0D11C7FE4

   Total Size:               900.2 GB (900174610944 Bytes) (exactly 1758153537 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    No
   Internal:                 No
```

However, I'm not sure why the fstab isn't working anymore or how I can correctly mount this drive. **How do you mount a NTFS drive as writable in OS X?**

Comment: Just readable? OS X allows you to read NTFS without using fstab.

Comment: Sorry, I ment "writable" :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  OS X does not have reliable r/w support for NTFS.

Purchase one of the reliable solutions, such as Paragon, or Tuxera.

Comment: Source? Many people claim works fine.